# Module absolute path not working in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying absolute module importing on Angular 16 but I am not having success. I believe this is actually a typescript feature rather than Angular.

I have `import { MiscService } from '@services/misc.service'`; in my component. Typescript linter/telesense finds it successfully in component. But when I run npm run start, I get the below error.

**Note**: If I change `"baseUrl": "./"` to `"baseUrl": "src"` then the typescript linter/telesense complains it can not find the path `@services/misc.service`. However, `"baseUrl": "./"` works.

**Note**: If I use the `import { MiscService } from '../../services/misc.service';` then I have no issues and the module is successful.

Any ideas why, please?

```
Error: src/app/reconcile/configure/identifier/identifier.component.ts:7:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/misc.service' or its corresponding type declarations.

7 import { MiscService } from '@services/misc.service';
```

tsconfig.json

```
 {
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "importHelpers": true,
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es2020",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
      ],
      "module": "esnext",
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths": {
        "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"],
        "@services/*": ["src/app/reconcile/services/*"]
      }
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
      "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
      "strictInjectionParameters": true
    }
  }
```